# Using glut with QT after update

Tags: qt, opengl, glut

I have a problem with update of my QT. I have decided to do an update from 5.2.1 to the newest, 5.8 version. Now I am trying to run my old project. There is something wrong with my graphic module, especially with functions connected with glut (I think so). I tried this week to solve this by myself, but now I am confused and tired.

Now I am using: Qt 5.8.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 5.3.0).

Originally I had the following libs only in my .pro file, end it works in QT 5.2.1:

LIBS += -lglut

But now, in new version of QT, I am getting such errors:

[Errors using the original project (with -lglut)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khj41.png)

When I change:

LIBS += -lglut

Into:

LIBS += -lopengl32

I am getting only such errors:

[Errors using -lopengl32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbdbb.png)

I do not know how to understand this "undefined reference". I see that glu.h is included in my project (as #include ). I can also see that "undefined" commands are recognized by the creator and glu.h is visible. I do not know how to solve this. Old QT 5.2.1. still is available in my computer and project successfully works. And also I have to tell You that I am not professional and I will be very grateful for any help and guidance.

Comment: opengl, glu and glut are three different things. Looks like glu is not passed to the linker.

Comment: @Velkan thank You for the answer. Is there a way to find/check the reason why glu is not passed?

Comment: Try `LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglut -lglu`

Comment: Hello @Velkan! Thank You for Your response. Unfortunately it doesn't help ;/ -lglu cause error so I have left two first libraries and I see the same errors like in (the same):

[Errors using -lopengl32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbdbb.png)

Comment: Keep searching for glu. I don't know, maybe on windows it's `-lglu32`.

Comment: @Velkan!!! Problem is resolved! :) I have successfully compiled my old program :) It was thank to You I was focused on right things. You told me to try `LIBS += -lopengl32 -lglu32`. An this works! I had another problem with my system variables not updated after Qt install and that is why I thought I still have an error in .pro file. I have also downloaded fresh _qwt_ library and successfully compiled it with new _mingw_ version. Now I do not worry about updating my framework. That was a good lesson for me. Thank You Velkan.